# Getting A StackOverFlowError when making a basic calcualator

Tags: java, calculator, stack-overflow

I am trying to make a calculator with 4 functions and that is word based. When I tried to implement the selecting of operations, I get a stackoverflow error.

Class Calculator:

```
package us.plexproductions.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static int firstnum;
public static int secondnum;
public static int answer;
public static int operation;

Calculator c = new Calculator();
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

static Operations o = new Operations();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    prompt();
    start();
}

public static void prompt() {
    System.out.println("########################");
    System.out.println("#Calculator Version 1.0#");
    System.out.println("########################");
    System.out.println("************************");
    System.out.println("This is a calculator that\ncan add, subtract, multiply, and divide\n" +
                       "multiple numbers at once.");
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("Start Calculating by Entering A Number and Then\nspelling out the operation you " +
                       "want to preform to that\nnumber and type in another number.");
}

public static void start() {
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter Your First Number: ");
    firstnum = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("Which operation would you like to use?\nAddition = 1, Subtraction = 2, Multiplication = 3, or Division = 4?");
    operation = s.nextInt();
    second();

}

public static void second() {
    if (operation == 1) {
        o.addition();
    }
    if (operation == 2) {
        o.subtraction();
    }
    if (operation == 3) {
        o.multiplication();
    }
    if (operation == 4) {
        o.division();
    }
}
}
```

Class Operations:

```
package us.plexproductions.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operations {

Calculator c = new Calculator();
Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);

public void addition() {
    System.out.println("Addition Selected.");
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
    Calculator.secondnum = s2.nextInt();
}

public void subtraction() {

}

public void multiplication() {

}

public void division() {

}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in a debugger? Dumping a lot of code here and saying "I get a stackoverflowerror! What's wrong?" doesn't show much effort to solve the problem youself. (You might look at the fact you have `Calculator c = new Calculator();` at the beginning of `Class Calculator`, which doesn't seem to be a good idea.)

Answer (score 6):

Each instance of `Calculator` creates a `new Calculator()` for the field `c`. These `Calculators`, in turn, create more `Calculators`, and so on.

The `StackOverflowError` occurs because this sequence of calls to the `Calculator` constructor never ends, filling up all the available stack memory. It doesn't appear that you *need* that nested `Calculator`, so try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

A `StackOverflowError` happens when you call too many functions, eating all [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) available. It may happen with recursive functions called too many times. For example, the following `factorial` function overflows on my machine:

```
public class Factorial {
    public static int factorial(int n){
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        factorial(10000);
    }
}
```

Now, where are you using recursion in your code?

```
public class Calculator{
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    ...
}
```